# Implementation of redirections in shells

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I am studying os from some notes, it gives a simple shell code as follows :

```
while (1) {
    printf ("$");
    readcommand (command, args);
    // parse user input
    if ((pid = fork ()) == 0) { // child?
       exec (command, args, 0);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
    // parent?
    wait (0);
    // wait for child to terminate
    } else {
    perror ("Failed to fork\n");
    }
}
```

And says for implementing `ls > tmp` we need to include the following lines before `exec`

```
close (1);
fd = open ("tmp1", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);
// fd will be 1!
```

And for `ls 2>tmp>tmp` we need to include

```
close(1);
close(2);
fd1 = open ("tmp1", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY);
fd2 = dup (fd1);
```

Can anyone explain me a little more about file descriptors in a simple sense and what does `close(1)` and `close(2)` do. And the input to close is a fd right, and `2` is error so what is `close(2)` doing ?

Comment: The close looks like it is closing the first file, going to next file closing it. Making variable fd1 open create file (named "tmp1") piped to this file opened in write and read only. create a variable fd2 and duplicate everything into fd2. Does that help?

Comment: BTW you're mistaken, what you are implementing here is a shell (the program interpreting the command line), not ls! And open/close/dup is here to implement shell redirections (i.e. `program > a_file`)

Comment: @ThomasMoulard sorry for that i have updated the question

Comment: and what is the value of `fd2` in the end . Is it 2 ?

Comment: *This isn't shell code.  It's C.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main question is about close(1) and close(2). Thus I am not going to view all of your code.

When the main function of your program is invoked, it already has three predefined streams open and available for use and their file descriptor are as following, they also are defined as macro.

```
 *STDIN_FILENO*
This macro has value 0, which is the file descriptor for standard input.

*STDOUT_FILENO*
This macro has value 1, which is the file descriptor for standard output.

*STDERR_FILENO*
This macro has value 2, which is the file descriptor for standard error output.
```

So when your close function do     close(1), it close standard output and when you do close(2), it close standard error output.

Note: Generally, these file descriptors are not closed until the process is going to be a daemon process.

Comment: The missing piece to still add is that the next `open()` will be assigned the first available file descriptor, i.e. fd1 (provided of course that you did not also close fd0).